# nl80211: Failed to set channel: -22 (Invalid argument)

Tags: wireless-networking, hostapd

i am trying to setup a wifi hotspot using hostapd with the following configuration:

```
interface=wlan0
ssid=My_AP
hw_mode=g
channel=2
auth_algs=1
wmm_enabled=0
ieee80211n=1
```

and i am getting this error once I have started the deamon:

```
Completing interface initialization
Mode: IEEE 802.11g  Channel: 2  Frequency: 2417 MHz
DFS 0 channels required radar detection
nl80211: Set freq 2417 (ht_enabled=1, vht_enabled=0, bandwidth=20 MHz, cf1=2417 MHz, cf2=0 MHz)
nl80211: Failed to set channel (freq=2417): -22 (Invalid argument)
Could not set channel for kernel driver
Interface initialization failed
```

what can be the issue here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check your wifi adapter/dongle capabilites with `iwconfig` - it might not supporting n mode.

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:on
```

if no mentioning n mode the remove `ieee80211n=1` from hostapd config file